# compatibility error with create Strapi app with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, strapi

```
npm --v: 
7.5.6
```

```
node -v
v15.9.0
```

```
npx create-strapi-app .
```

i am trying to create strapi app with MongoDB Atlas, but i get this error with i dont understand..

> Connection test failed: Command failed: yarnpkg --cwd C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\strapic1eac7442b18 add strapi-connector-mongoose@3.5.3
> error strapi-connector-mongoose@3.5.3:
> The engine "node" is incompatible with this module.
> Expected version `>=10.16.0 <=14.x.x`. Got `15.9.0`
> error Found incompatible module.

so: Expected version `>=10.16.0 <=14.x.x`. ??? of what? my node version?
is this is mean strapi is far behind with node?
how to solve this?

Comment: ok... i am new... i have windows10 64bit and n-npm would not work... will npm install -g node@14.14.0 will do?

Comment: ok... uninstall node and npm and install nvm.

Comment: yes: nvm did the trik :) thanks...

Answer (score 0):

> of what?  my node version?

yes

> is this is mean strapi is far behind with node? how to solve this?

use **node** with vesion between `10.16.0` and `14.x.x`